# Append current url in screenshot name

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I need to add current url in screenshot file name.

Here is code:

from selenium import webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.save_screenshot("image.png") # save a screenshot to disk
print driver.current_url
driver.quit()
```

How to replace image.png with driver.current_url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific example given in your question:

```
driver.save_screenshot(driver.current_url.replace('://','_'))
```

More generally, since your problem stems from the special characters, you can do something like:

```
chars = [':','/','%'] # add more if needed
image_name = driver.current_url
for char in chars:
    image_name = image_name.replace(char,'_')
driver.save_screenshot(image_name)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Working without problems